# How to make a suggestion box

Tags: html, forms, client, server

I am trying to make a suggestion box so that way I can see what my viewers think would make my site better. Here is some code that I have.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <label>
    <textarea name="input" id="input" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
  </label>
</form>
<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="">
  <label>
    <input type="submit" name="export" id="export" value="Submit" />
  </label>
</form>`
```

But this is all I have. It seems to work client side but not server side. Can someone tell me what language and if you know the code that I would have to use that would be great.

Comment: Please help me if you can. Also I know some people may think I am a bad poster but I have learned.

Comment: Can you provide information about your platform?  OS, Web Server, Database etc.

Comment: "what language" — You can use any programming language you like providing your server supports it or you are willing to change server to one that does. Recommending one is off-topic for Stackoverflow, as is recommending a prewritten script.

Comment: 1. Post to another HTML file `action="myformresults.html"`

Answer (score 0):

1. Post to another HTML file `action="myformresults.html"`
2. Post to a server side scripting language like PHP `action="myphpformresult.php"` which will 'do things' and then render an HTML document or any other thing (like send as email).
3. You can call a Javascript function to handle the form.

I would recommend PHP.

You can access a post variable in PHP by name:
HTML `<input name="postVar">`
PHP `$myVar = $_POST['postVar'];`

Comment: 1. That won't do anything except load the HTML file. 2. That's far from a complete answers to the (far too broad in the first place) question.

Comment: Do I have to download the php software in order to write/use it? I am new to php and don't fully understand.

Answer (score 0):

all you need is writing a jquery code as follows in your html file: //note that i rewrite your html code as no need for two forms

```
      <html>
        <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

        <script>
    function submitters(){
    event.preventDefault();

        $.post( "mail.php.txt", $( "#form1" ).serialize(),function( data ) {
$("#formcontainer").fadeOut("slow");
$("#formcontainer").html(data);
    } );
    }
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="formcontainer">
        <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
            <label>
            <textarea name="input" id="input" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
            </label>
            <input Onclick="submitters()" type="button" name="export" id="export" value="Submit" />

            </form>
    </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

then in mail.php file something like

```
<?php
$input=$_POST['input'];
$to      = 'youremail@domain.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = $input;
$headers = 'From: website.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: There is no need to involve JavaScript, and you've made several errors in yours so it won't even run anyway.

Comment: you can extend the jquery function to display a nice thank you message , through a callback function , without having the visitor to navigate to another page or reload the page itself, yet you need to add filters and validation to variables before sending,

Comment: try again :) i did some changes

Comment: Now it works. It's about a million miles from [best practises](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and is still entirely unnecessary, bit it works.

Comment: its all about how do you want it to behave..if you dont want users to navigate to action file , then do not use the jquery i wrote and just write the mail.php in action attribute in your form , and add the following code in your php if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){echo 'we received your email thank you ';}

Comment: and if you want to use the same page as action file , just write your php under your html , and change attribute to action="" , and add the if statement i mentioned in my previous comment , and remove the jquery code

Comment: If I follow your way how will I be able to see the suggestions?

Comment: I have tried and it says "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///F:/HTML/mail.php.txt. Cross     jquery-1.11.2.min.is:4 origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resorce. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: dear you need to write correct path to your php file     function submitters(){
    event.preventDefault();

        $.post( "pathtophpfile", $( "#form1" ).serialize(),function( data ) {
$("#formcontainer").fadeOut("slow");
$("#formcontainer").html(data);
    } );
    }

Comment: and you will recieve suggestions via Email in your inbox

Comment: @HatemAhmed Where would I put that code? I barely know any commands in php